# How to call the async Task Function?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await

My code for class AllWebApiOperations is

```
public AllWebApiOperations(string apiURI)
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiURI);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string route)
    {
        string result= string.Empty;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(route);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I'm calling this in button click

```
    string apiURI = @"http://localhost:35487/";
    private async void btnCallWebApi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllWebApiOperations op = new AllWebApiOperations(apiURI);
        var result = await op.GetDataAsync(apiURI + "api/products/");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

My code web api is working properly as shown below

[image]

But I'm getting error while calling the function as shown below

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, tried googling but can't find resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string route)
{
    string result= string.Empty;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(route);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        **result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();**
    }
    return result;
}
```

I should be using

```
**result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();**
```